# Removing duplicates from a list in a nested dictionary using setdefault()

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm creating a nested dictionary where the inner dictionaries value part will be a list that should maintain order. I can achieve a solution but I would like to do this when I first create the dictionary(dict1) instead of using another dictionary(dict2) to achieve this? I have omitted some code for simplicity and possible confusion since I'm using ignition designer which uses jython as its interpreter. The idea for the most part should be self explanatory.

> ```
> example: {20:{Mon Apr 04 00:00:00 CDT 2022: [90, 90, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}} = 
>
>          {20:{Mon Apr 04 00:00:00 CDT 2022: [90, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}}
> ```

```
dict1, dict2 = defaultdict(dict), defaultdict(dict)

# Nested dictionary with duplicates and order.
for i in dataset1:
    for j dataset2:
       dict1[i[0]].setdefault(j[0], []).append(round(j[1], 2))

# Nested dictionary with no duplicates and no order.
for i in dataset1:
    for j dataset2:
        dict1[i[0]].setdefault(j[0], set()).add(round(j[1], 2))

# Here I'm able to remove the duplicates and keep order but would like to do this
# when I'm first creating the dictionary (dict1)?
dict2 = {i:{j:sorted(set(k), key=k.index) for j, k in dict1[i].items()} for i in dict1}
```

Comment: There is no order-preserving set, unfortunately, but what if you used a dict with `None` values?

Comment: While creating your first ```dict```, you can use ```if-else``` statement to check if the value is already in ```list``` or not. Then append the new value only if its not already there.

Comment: Step back from your computer and think about what logic you need to put in your nested for loops to achieve what you want. Don't worry about doing it in a single line. Write the steps on a piece of paper in words, then translate those words into python code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I got what I wanted and found a solution but I was just trying to save a step by doing the logic in the first dictionary.

Comment: @Musclemania05 I agree that building the dict the way you want it to begin with would be better. My suggestion above was an attempt to point you in the direction I would try if I were solving this myself.

Comment: I appreciate you for that thanks @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 1):

`dict` or - traditionally - `collections.OrderedDict` preserve insertion order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

class OrderedSet(OrderedDict):
    def add(self, x):
        self[x] = None

>>> dict1 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(OrderedSet))
>>> dict1[1][2].add(4)
>>> dict1[1][2].add(3)
>>> dict1[1][2].add(5)
>>> dict1[1][2].add(4)
>>> list(dict1[1][2])
[4, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Note that you might not even need to convert the dict into a `list` to use it -- for example, you can iterate over a dict's keys (in order) exactly the same way you iterate over a list.

Comment: Yep, this is just for presentational purposes.

Comment: @user2390182 this doesn't work though went iterating over a nested list such:

Comment: list1 = [
    [1, 10, 4.98],
    [1, 10, 1.98],
    [1, 10, 4.98],
    [1, 20, 2.98],
    [1, 30, 3.98],
    [1, 40, 4.98],

]

Comment: 1 defaultdict(<class '__main__.OrderedSet'>, {10: OrderedSet([(4.98, None), (1.98, None)]), 20: OrderedSet([(2.98, None)]), 30: OrderedSet([(3.98, None)]), 40: OrderedSet([(4.98, None)])})
OrderedSet([(4.98, None), (1.98, None)])

Comment: @user2390182 I see that it does remove the duplicates but still an extra step would be required to convert to list. As said above was seeing if there was a way to save a step and do it on the first dictionary (dict1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `Python-2.7` you can use `OrderedDict` to get ordered set as dict does not preserve order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def ordered_set(values):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for v in values:
        d[v] = None
    return list(d.keys())

dict1 = {k: {k2: ordered_set(v2) for k2, v2 in dict1[k].items()} for k,v in dict1.items()}
```

Comment: remember the data that's being performed on, is a dataset which translates to a nested list or list of list. Your dictionary comprehension is referencing back the the same dictionary?

Comment: MYousefi This is what the list would look like for example:                                                              list1 = [[1, 10, 4.98], [1, 10, 1.98], [1, 10, 4.98], [1, 20, 2.98], [1, 30, 3.98], [1, 40, 4.98]]

Comment: Maybe I'm a confused a bit. I saw the example which looks like a dictionary of dictionaries. The second line looked like it was still a dictionary with the duplicates removed in the list value of the inner dictionary. That's what I produced.